# UItextField.text return nil for a programmatically created UItextfield (While I already input some text inside...)

Tags: swift, uitextfield

New to swift I did spend 4 days already now and stuck to this I believe very easy task which doesn't make any more sense to me.
When I create UItextfiled with the storyboard I do have no issues getting back and forth UItextfield.text

When the UItextfiled.text is create programmatically like th example below "textProjectNumber"
then even if I enter the project number inside the urtextfiled , and try to call for the text later on in the same class it seems like the text is = nil .... Can you please help me to understand where is the issues.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let textProjectNumber = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    textProjectNumber.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textProjectNumber.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    textProjectNumber.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    textProjectNumber.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
    textProjectNumber.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    textProjectNumber.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    textProjectNumber.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    textProjectNumber.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
    textProjectNumber.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
    textProjectNumber.tag = 1
    textProjectNumber.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    textProjectNumber.delegate = self
    
    // add the uitextfield in the view
    
    self.view.addSubview(textProjectNumber)
    
    //add the constrain for this uitextfield
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textProjectNumber.centerXAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
        textProjectNumber.centerYAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])
    
    textProjectName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textProjectName.delegate = self


     // MARK: - Navigation
 
    // Enable the Save button only if the text field has a valid project name.
    
        updateSaveButtonState()
    
}

//MARK: UItextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    
    textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    if textField.tag == 2 { // tag 2 = textProjectName tag1 = textProjNumber
        textField.autocorrectionType = .yes
    }
    textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    
    //Hide the keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
    
}




func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //update the status of the buttong when we finish editing the uI textfiled
    updateSaveButtonState()

    //add the title of this new project creation with textfiled + PF-
    if textProjectName.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
    navigationItem.title = "PF-" + textProjectName.text! }
    textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    
    // Disable the Save button while editing.
    saveNewProjectButton.isEnabled = false
    createbuttonsinkeyboard(textField)
    if textField.tag == 2 {
        textField.autocorrectionType = .yes
    } else {
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    }
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    if textField.tag == 1 {


        if range.length + range.location > (textField.text?.count)! {
            return false
        }
        
        
        let newLenght = (textField.text?.count)! + string.count - range.length
        if (textField.text?.contains("PF-"))! {
            textField.text! = textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: "PF-", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
            
        }
        print("do i do that")
        return newLenght <= 8
    }

    return true
}



//MARK: Private Methods
private func updateSaveButtonState(){
    

    // Disable the Save button if the text field is empty.

    if textProjectName.text?.isEmpty ?? false || ((textProjectName.text?.isEmpty) != false) {
        saveNewProjectButton.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        saveNewProjectButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}


//MARK: Create object function with keyboard


@objc func Done(){
    
   view.endEditing(true)
        let numbFromUser = textProjectNumber.text
    if activeTextField.tag == 1 {
        textProjectNumber.text = "PF-" + numbFromUser!
   
    }
    print(numbFromUser!)

     
}


@objc func Cancel(){
    self.activeTextField.text = ""
}

//save button function
@IBAction func SaveNewProject() {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController (title: "WARNING", message: "CREAT A NEW PROJECT WITH THE FOLLOWING INFO:\n\(textProjectNumber.text ?? "Empty") \n\(textProjectNumber.text ?? "Empty")", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.gotoFouthViewController(/*add argument if needed*/)
        
        
    }
    //cancel the alert
    let cancelaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        
    }
    actionSheet.addAction(okaction)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancelaction)
    present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    
}
func gotoFouthViewController() {
    //push or present the fourth view controller here
    let home = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homepage") as! ViewController
    // secondVC.statusDelegate = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(home, animated: true)
}

func createbuttonsinkeyboard(_ textField: UITextField) {

    // self.activeTextField.text is an optional, we safely unwrap it here
   self.activeTextField = textField
        //      // Create a toolbar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40))
        //toolBar.sizeToFit()
      

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(Done))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let emptyButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.cancel, target: self, action: #selector(Cancel))

        // Add a toolbar buttons in each textfiled
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        toolBar.setItems([emptyButton,spaceButton,doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

        return;
      }


  }

this help me to fid constraint auto or not
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

override public var description: String {
    let id = identifier ?? ""
    return "id: \(id), constant: \(constant)" //you may print whatever you want here
     }

 }
```

Comment: Where are you getting `nil`?

Comment: You can see that if you fill up the uiaction alert nothing will appear . Strange really ...